# Form containing with ViewComponent

Tags: asp.net-core, model-binding, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

I couldn't figure out how to use ViewComponent inside form

The form is rendered correctly (value in the dropdown), but the model binding, when posting form, fail

This is the view

```
<form asp-action="" method="post">
    <div asp-validation-summary="All"></div>
    <div class="row">
        <vc:periodi model="@(Model.Periodi)"></vc:periodi>
    </div>
```

This is the ViewComponent

```
<div class="col-2">
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(a => a.Anno)
                    .DataTextField("Text")
                    .DataValueField("Value")
                    .BindTo(Model.Anni)
                    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 100%" }))
```

No matter what I choose in the dropdown, the variable Anno inside the Object Periodi of the Model is null

I checked the rendered HTML

```
<input id="Anno" name="Anno" ...
```

I think, based on my experience with MVC, that should be something like "Periodi.Anno" for the model binder to work.
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your experience, the name should be `Periodi.Anno` to bind the ViewComponent property.

As my test with `input` tag like below:

```
<input asp-for="Name" name="MVCSubModel.Name" class="form-control" />
```

I suggest you try :

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(a => a.Anno)
                .DataTextField("Text")
                .DataValueField("Value")
                .BindTo(Model.Anni)
                .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 100%"; name = "Periodi.Anno" }))
```

Comment: Yeah, I've tried your solutions and it works. The problem is that there're two object linked with the hardcoded name of MVCSubModel and it shoulden't. What if I change the name of the property? Well for know the important is the result, perhaps i should write an issue to GitHub

Comment: @FrancescoVenturini What do you mean by two object? For another option, I would suggest you try passing entire object from view to viewcomponent like `<vc:periodi model="@(Model)"></vc:periodi>` and `.BindTo(Model.Periodi.Anni)`